# align chart columns left/right

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to align columns to the left in my chart.  By default they are in the middle.

I can't find anything about this in the API documentation.

[image]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pyccki/SnPsP/398/) is a jsFiddle test.

Comment: Here's Working jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pyccki/SnPsP/528/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the highcharts api, have you examined the group padding feature? 
http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-column--groupPadding

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        groupPadding: 0
    }
},
```

If the columns appear too wide when you set the groupPadding to 0, 
you can still play with the pointPadding. http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-column--pointPadding

(If that doesn't fit your needs, I guess I'm a bit perplexed, 
because I don't see how having chart columns aligned to the left, 
then followed by a big blank space on the right, would make 
for a well-designed chart...)

Comment: thanx mg1075 !!! groupPadding:0 worked for me, now i just have to make my columns narrow, once i change groupPadding it made my columns wide.  Here's updated http://jsfiddle.net/SnPsP/402/

Comment: @pyccki: if you want to narrow the width of the columns, play with the pointPadding.  e.g., "groupPadding: 0, pointPadding: 0.25".

Comment: Is there any solution for lineChart?

Answer (score 1):

you can trying using the margin option http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--margin

or the margin left option http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--marginLeft

or the spacing left option http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--spacingLeft

Comment: "spacingLeft" moves entire chart not columns.
"marginLeft" also doesn't work